# Remote working for indian citizens

Tags: working-visas, indian-citizens

I live in India and a citizen by birth. 
Am I eligible to work for remote jobs which are posted on "StackOverflow" by organizations from US, Canada and Europe?
For example, the below job says the position is fully remote.
https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/183484/python-developer-web-crawling-scrapinghub?so=i&pg=1&offset=3&tl=python

Though I will be working from India but since the organization is based out in North America or Europe, do I require any working VISA?

Could you please share some knowledge on this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

A [visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travel_visa) is a country's permission that you physically enter that country. If, for example, you wished to travel to the US, you would need to have a visa. Without a visa, you'd be turned away at the US border or refused boarding onto your airplane flight to the US. Because "working remotely" for a US company doesn't involve physically crossing the border into the US, you don't need a visa to work remotely.

However: a) there may well be tax or other status requirements placed upon you by the Indian government if you work remotely, and b) if your remote employer requires you to come to the home office for a meeting or other work, you would then need to secure a visa in order to make the trip.